# Set query result as variable

Tags: variables, netezza

I want to save the output of a query as a variable for use in further queries. The variable in question is the first day of the month.

I can do it manually:

```
\set startdate '2016-10-01'
```

I can write a query to do it:

```
select date_trunc('month', now());
```

Returns:

```
     DATE_TRUNC
---------------------
 2016-10-01 00:00:00
(1 row)
```

But I can't store the query output as the variable using:

```
\set startdate 'select date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '1 day';'
```

Returns an error.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion:

Put the data into a TEMP table with one row and one column, then 'join' to it whenever you need your 'variable'